# How to deploy a standalone java server application to a J2EE container

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, java-server

Greetings to the experts

I have a java server application (the kind of application, with a main, that you run as a service and that provides services via various ports using standard and/or proprietary protocols) that works great standalone. How can I deploy it to a J2EE container (such as jBoss AS) so to gain administration and operational benefits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't servlet container, such as tomcat sufficient for you ?
It would be easier to be spec compliant when deploying on servlet container.
On application server you cannot open custom ports.

If you still want to do it on application server [j2ee_connector-1_0][1]

[1]: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/first/jsr016/j2ee_connector-1_0.pdf can be helpful.